# ¿Dónde se guardan los archivos BLOB de phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, blob

Estoy haciendo un programa donde envío imágenes de cualquier dispositivo a la base de datos de mi computadora en phpmyadmin, y me muestra las imágenes en el navegador.

Estoy usando el tipo `longblob` para las imágenes y se guardan las imágenes en formato `.bin`.

Almaceno las imágenes con php de esta manera:

```
<?php
    include("conexion.php");

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $Imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['Imagen']['tmp_name']));
    $query = "INSERT INTO tabla_imagen(nombre,Imagen) VALUES('$nombre','$Imagen')";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($query);

    if($resultado)
    {
        header("Location: mostrar.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No se inserto";
    }
?>
```

Ésta es la base de datos donde guardo las imágenes:

[image: Base de datos en phpmyadmin]

Mi duda es que yo quiero que en otro programa busque e imprima esa imagen, el problema es:

1. No sé dónde es que se guardan esos archivos.
2. Si de php o c++, es posible descargar las imágenes de la base de datos?

Cualquier comentario es bienvenido.

Comment: ¿Qué usas? ¿[PDO/mysql](http://php.net/pdo-mysql), [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli)? ¿Cuál es el motivo o limitación que te impide guardar las imágenes directamente en el sistema de archivos en vez de la base de datos?

Comment: Hola @JoséT. ¿podrías responder mi comentario para poder ayudarte mejor? Gracias.

Comment: Por supuesto, utilizo phpmyadmin como base de datos, y me conecto desde php de esta manera: `$conexion = new mysqli("192.168.0.x","Jose","","imagen");`. Y la razón por la que estoy guardando archivos en la base de datos, es porque estoy tomando una foto de mi teléfono móvil y la envío a mi ordenador a la base de datos. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Gracias, con eso podré ayudarte. Por lo pronto quería hacerte saber que para conseguir lo que quieres no necesitas almacenar la imagen en la base de datos. Se puede subir usando PHP, pero luego puedes almacenar el archivo en el disco duro y luego descargarlo desde allí, descargando de esa tarea a PHP y la base de datos.

Comment: Excelente hermano, espero tu respuesta que no he logrado descargar la imagen.

Comment: Siento la tardanza, tengo un tiempo limitado para colaborar en la web y tu respuesta requería mucho tiempo y dedicación para responderla. Ya tienes mi respuesta, espero que te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El título de tu pregunta es ambiguo, pero trataré de explicar las respuestas más adecuadas.

**¿Dónde se guardan los archivos Blob de phpmyadmin?**

Obviamente se guardan en el espacio de tablas (tablespace) de la tabla y base de datos MySQL que `phpMyAdmin` está usando.

A su vez MySQL aloja la información contenida en las tablas (metadatos) en su espacio de tablas `innoDB` que, por defecto, es un archivo llamado [`ibdata1`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_system_tablespace).

En caso de tener activada la opción [`innodb_file_per_table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) (activada por defecto a partir de MySQL 5.7) los metadatos del espacio de tablas se guarda en un directorio con el nombre de la base de datos usando el mismo nombre que la tabla con extensión `.ibd`.

Como todos los metadatos se guardan en un mismo archivo (todas los archivos que subas a la tabla) no es posible acceder a ellos de forma sencilla e individual, sólo es sencillo hacerlo a través de consultas SQL.

**¿Por qué `phpMyAdmin` descarga mi archivo con extensión `.bin`?**

`phpMyAdmin` sólo conoce el formato del campo, `LONGBLOB`, y su contenido. Al descargarlo no tiene conocimiento del nombre de archivo original, por lo que automáticamente genera uno compuesto por el nombre de la tabla, el texto `blob` y la extensión `.bin`.

**¿Cómo puedo solucionar la descarga del archivo con el nombre original?**

Para realizar esta tarea primero deberás proporcionar un alojamiento al nombre del archivo en el momento de almacenarlo en la base de datos.

Para ello deberás cambiar el esquema y agregar el nombre de archivo a la tabla (puedes hacerlo usando la pestaña "SQL" de `phpMyAdmin`):

```
ALTER TABLE `tabla_imagen`
ADD COLUMN `nombre_archivo` TEXT DEFAULT ''
```

Al hacer esto se creará un nuevo campo con valor `NULL` para los registros existentes, por lo que podemos rellenar un valor inicial (para facilitarte su edición más tarde) de la siguiente manera:

```
UPDATE `tabla_imagen` SET `nombre_archivo` = CONCAT(nombre, '.jpg')
```

He presupuesto que las imágenes son `JPEG`, pero podrían ser otro formato o ser otro tipo de archivo, recae en tus manos modificar manualmente el nombre en aquellos que necesites.

**IMPLEMENTACIÓN: ¿Cómo subo un archivo para que mantenga su nombre?**

Hay que modificar el PHP que recibe el formulario para soportar esto:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['Imagen'])) {
    include 'conexion.php';

    /* Preparamos la consulta */
    $consulta = $conexion->prepare('
      INSERT INTO tabla_imagen (nombre, Imagen, nombre_archivo)
      VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    ');
    if ($consulta === false) {
        die('Error: ' . $conexion->error);
    }
    /* Asignamos los parámetros: "s"tring, "b"lob, "s"tring */
    $null = NULL;
    $consulta->bind_param(
      'sbs',
      $_POST['nombre'],
      $null, /* Importante con longblog y debe ser variable (por referencia) */
      $_FILES['Imagen']['name']
    );
    /* Importante si es tipo longblob */
    $consulta->send_long_data(1, file_get_contents($_FILES['Imagen']['tmp_name']));
    /* Ejecutamos la consulta */
    if ($consulta->execute() === true) {
      header('Location: mostrar.php');
      die();
    } else {
      die('No se inserto');
    }
}
?><form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" />
    <input type="file" name="Imagen" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**IMPLEMENTACIÓN: ¿Cómo descargo un archivo con su nombre original?**

Hay que obtener el archivo desde la base de datos y generar una cabecera que incluya dicho nombre para que sea entendido por el navegador y no lo guarde con el nombre y extensión (`.php`) del script que obtiene la imagen:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  /* Preparamos la consulta buscando por id */
  $consulta = $conexion->prepare('
    SELECT Imagen, nombre_archivo
    FROM tabla_imagen
     WHERE id = ?
  ');
  if ($consulta === false) {
      die('Error: ' . $conexion->error);
  }
  /* Asignamos la id proporcionada desde el parámetro a la consulta */
  $consulta->bind_param(
    'i',
    $_GET['id']
  );
  /* Realizamos la consulta */
  $consulta->execute();
  /* Almacenamos los datos (importante en el caso del blob) */
  $consulta->store_result();
  /* Asignamos la salida a dos variables */
  $consulta->bind_result($datos, $nombre);
  /* Obtenemos el registro y lo asignamos a las variables */
  if ($consulta->fetch() === false) {
      die('Archivo no encontrado');
  }
  /* Generamos las cabeceras para forzar la descarga de un archivo con nombre */
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  /* Enviamos el tamaño de archivo */
  header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($datos));
  /* Limpiamos del nombre de archivo caracteres extraños */
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' .
    addslashes(preg_replace('/[^[:alnum:].,\-_ ]/', '_', $nombre)) . '"');
  /* Enviamos al navegador el archivo */
  die($datos);
}
/* Mostramos listado de archivos */
$consulta = $conexion->query('
  SELECT id, nombre, nombre_archivo
  FROM tabla_imagen
');
if ($consulta !== false) {
  while ($resultado = $consulta->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<p>
  <a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?id=<?= urlencode($resultado['id']) ?>">
    <?= htmlspecialchars($resultado['nombre']) ?>
    (<?= htmlspecialchars($resultado['nombre_archivo']) ?>)
  </a>
</p>
  <?php }
} else {
  die('Error: ' . $conexion->error);
}
```

Comment: Yo te agradezco muchisimo, me ha funcionado a la perfección. Tengo muchas dudas en tu código, pero esta tan bien explicado que lo empezaré a estudiar.

Comment: No te quedes con ninguna duda, intentaré mejorar la respuesta para aclarartela. Pregúntame y si es demasiado extenso o se sale del tema te recomendaré una nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

No recomiendo acessar las imagenes archivado directamente. Es mejor descargar las imagenes de la base de datos por una conexión de cliente. Por ejemplo, en PHP, puedes usar ...:

```
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT image FROM images WHERE whatever=?"); 
$statement->bind_param("i", $image_id);
$statement->execute();
$statement->store_result();
$statement->bind_result($image);
$statement->fetch();
```

Ahora la imagen es en `$image`; puedes archivarla por [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php).

(Por favor perdone my pobre español, todavia estoy aprendiendo...)

**Añadí 2017-05-23**: Si deseas archivar la imagen, usas códigi como...:

```
$path = "/Users/johndoe/Desktop/my_image.png"; // replace with your own path
if (!file_put_contents($image, $path)) {
    echo("Something went wrong.");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su aporte. Debería hacer una visita a [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para obtener ayuda acerca de cómo redactar correctamente una respuesta. Como el autor de la pregunta no ha proporcionado información acerca de la tabla, campo, interfaz (PDO o mysqli), etc, deberías preguntar mediante un comentario (como hice yo hace unas horas) y esperar su respuesta para proporcionar una respuesta específica y no una ambigua o que quizá ni tan siquiera use la interfaz correcta. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda ya modifique el código y también incluí la conexión. Pero me da el error donde no declare una variable: **Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli**. Me puede indicar en que estoy equivocado. Y una pregunta mas, este código me descarga la imagen automáticamente la imagen? Y muy buen español amigo!

Comment: `$mysqli` represente la conexión a la base de datos (como `$conexion` que usas en tu código.) Si usas mysqli, puedes sustituir `$conexion` por `$mysqli` facilmente. He añadido un ejemplo para archivar la imagen (y he reparado un eror en la última linea - `$stmt` -> `$statement`).