# ¿Hay alguna forma de manejar un blob (un archivo guardado en mysql) sin tener que crear un archivo?

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito recuperar un blob del db, que puede ser cualquier tipo de archivo, img, texto, video, etc. y poder mostrarlo en html.

Comment: Lo seleccionas como cualquier otra columna, y al mostrarlo lo tratas como una imagen. [Aquí tienes bien explicado dos formas de hacerlo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34112174/5587982). Crea tu código y si tienes algún problema, edita la pregunta con ese problema concreto y el código que has creado.

Comment: Sí, es posible. Comparte una prueba de concepto en la que hayas tratado de hacer esta tarea y te corrijo/completo el código. Échale mientras un vistazo a esta otra pregunta que respondí acerca de un tema muy similar (es probable que esta pregunta sea un duplicado de ella): [¿Dónde se guardan los archivos BLOB de phpmyadmin?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71897/dónde-se-guardan-los-archivos-blob-de-phpmyadmin/72629#72629)